# Как заставить бота ответить только один раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Текст приветствия должен быть выведен в ответ на сообщение с любым текстовым содержанием, но в дальнейшем функция приветствия не должна реагировать на остальные сообщения

То бишь функцию приветствия нужно совершить только один раз, а потом деактивировать

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['begin'])
def commands_list(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вот список комманд, которые я умею выполнять:')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '/first_command - выполняет комманду 1')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['first_command'])
def func_description(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите параметры первой комманды')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, report)


def report(message):
    bot.send_message('id_of_my_chat', message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Спасибо, параметры будут переданы админимстратору')


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=["text"])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Текст привестсвтия')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Для начала работы со мной нажми /begin')
```

Comment: Зачем это всё? Есть команда `/start`, её пропустить невозможно. Приветствуйте после неё и проблема решена

Answer (score -1):

Если вам нужно приветствовать пользователь один раз за все время, то вы можете завести в базе данных таблицу с пользователями и флагом, было ли приветствие. При получении сообщения проверять флаг и принимать решение, какое пользователю отправлять сообщение.

Если вам нужно приветствовать пользователя каждый раз, когда он запускает бота (после остановки или блокировки), то вы можете отвечать приветствием на команду  /start.